"He said Thursday that..." or "He said on Thursday that..."
In most newspaper articles I've found that the sentence is portrayed in the following fashion: The US Prez said Thursday that he would...
Isn't this wrong grammar, or am I missing some rule?

You could picture the sentence as saying "Thursday, he said that..." No preposition. "Today he said that..." "Last year he ..."

It sounds like you may have been reading American material. American speakers and writers very often don't use the preposition 'on' when discussing days (e.g. I'll gladly pay you Tuesday), whereas British ones mostly do (I'll gladly pay you on Tuesday). One notable exception is the New York Times:

Britain announced on Monday that it would suspend the export of some
weapons to Israel

